# Problem with Java Runtime.exec() when trying to start Nmap.exe

Tags: java, command-prompt, runtime.exec, nmap

I'm using Java 1.6 , Eclipse , Windows 7.
I'm trying to run commands in a java program to use NMAP.

The code :

`String cmd[] = { "cmd.exe", "/c","start notepad.exe"};`

Process pr = rt.exec(cmd);

works fine, but the code:

`String cmd[] = { "cmd.exe", "/c","start nmap.exe"};`

Process pr = rt.exec(cmd);

simply doesn't.

I tried both commands in the command prompt, they both work fine but the latter one fails when I try it with the Runtime.exec(). What would be the problem ?

Thanks, in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe ["When Runtime.exec() won't"](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html) can help you.

The reason the command works in a command shell and not in Java might be that the command shell has the advantage of being able to refer to the PATH environment variable to find it; Java cannot.  I'll bet if you put the full path to Nmap.exe that you'll fare better.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! I read that article many times but couldn't find the answer in there. Unfortunately, I think, the problem is not about that 4 pitfalls.

What I don't understand is why the same type of command works with a native program like notepad and doesn't with NMAP. When using Runtime.exec(), windows simply forgets the whereabouts of NMAP.
 I'm getting a error that says  "Windows cannot find 'nmap.exe'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again". But the same command works with the command prompt.

Comment: "I'm getting a error that says "Windows cannot find 'nmap.exe'."  - Then the problem is *clearly* that `nmap.exe` cannot be found on the PATH that `cmd.exe` is using when executed via `Process.exec(...)`.  Use the full pathname for `nmap.exe` and it should work.